# Cannot find Hangouts

Tags: android, android-applicationinfo, google-hangouts

I have the method below. It gets all the apps on a device and looks for particular ones by name: Hangouts, Skype, Viber, WhatsApp. All 4 are installed on a Motorola Droid MAXX running Android 4.4.4. and a Samsung SM-T530NU with 5.0.2.

On both devices, it does not find Hangouts. Any ideas why this is?

Output:

> com.skype.raider/.Main m=0x108000}  Intent filter: null
>   com.viber.voip/.WelcomeActivity m=0x108000}  Intent filter: null
>   com.whatsapp/.Main m=0x108000}  Intent filter: null

I removed the if condition and list all the apps and search by hand (so to speak). I saw nothing about hangouts, hang, ho, ...

```
public static List<ResolveInfo> getAllInstalledApps(Context context) {

        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        List<ResolveInfo> appsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);

        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : appsList) {
            String infoString = resolveInfo.toString();
            if (infoString.contains("hangouts") ||
                infoString.contains("skype") ||
                infoString.contains("viber") ||
                infoString.contains("whatsapp")) {

                Log.i("getAllInstalledApps", resolveInfo.toString() + "  Intent filter: " + resolveInfo.filter);
            }
        }
        return appsList;
    }
```

Comment: A note after the fact: [Google Hangouts is no longer supported](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/support-faq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app package name for Hangouts is actually `com.google.android.talk`.  You should be looking for that.  A tip for looking for package names is to go to the URL of the product page.  It's part of the `id` query in the URL.  For example, the URL for Google Hangouts is:

`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.talk`